# How do you make grep print the output of it's search so far while it's still searching

Tags: grep

When I run a grep search with a lot of results, it gives me a blank screen, and then spits the results all out at once when it's done. How to I make it print the results AS it finds them? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using GNU grep, try using the `--line-buffered` option.